How can I port-forward submariner services, i.e serviceimport crds serviceimports.multicluster.x-k8s.io
Submariner can be used to connect multiple smaller k8s clusters and then export (serviceexport CRD) or import (serviceimport CRD) in the connected clusters.
When testing code it would be nice to be able to port-forward these services no matter which of the k8s clusters the current context is attached to, so port-forwarding the ServiceImport objects or potentially manually resolving them and port-forwarding based on cluster ips or similar would be great.
How can this be accomplished?  I.e. you have 10 services on 5 clusters, all available on all clusters using ServiceImport objects and submariner.  The current context is pointing to one of these 5 clusters.  You want the 10 services available at localhost:1000...1010 - how can this be accomplished?

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

In gcp we have service called multi-cluster Services, In kubernetes you have Multicluster Services API , When you export a Service with MCS, that Service is then available across all of the clusters in your fleet, similarly
Submariner Service Imports (serviceImport CRDs) allow you to expose services running in one cluster as services in another cluster. This facilitates service discovery and load balancing across clusters.
You can find more information about this in this blog by wghdr(translate the page to english)
